# How do you emit a Socket IO message from a button click when there is a button in each row of a Bootstrap table that has a unique ID?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, bootstrap-table, flask-socketio

I have made a Flask web application that uses a Bootstrap table to display information. In each row, a user can change a dropdown and update a notes text area. I want both of these actions to be able to update on all connected clients with the updated information instead of having to refresh the page.

My first question is if Socket IO is the right API I should be using.

I have had success with using Socket IO to update a single notes section on a different web page.

```
HTML:
<form method="POST">
<div class="input-group">
    <textarea class="info form-control custom-control" rows="2" style="resize:none" id="noteTextArea" 
        name="note">{{ milestone.info }}</textarea>
    <button id="milestoneInfo" class="input-group-addon btn btn-outline-secondary">Update</button>
</div>
</form>

JAVASCRIPT:
$( '#milestoneInfo' ).on( 'click', function()
{
    let milestone_info = $( 'textarea.info' ).val()
    let milestone_id = '{{ milestone.id }}'
    console.log ( milestone_info )
    socket.emit( 'milestone info', { milestone_info : milestone_info, milestone_id : milestone_id } )
} )
```

I believe this doesn't work in a table because you can't have buttons with the same ID.
And, I get this in the debug console in VS Code: "Found 9 elements with non-unique id #approved"

```
$( '#approved' ).on( 'click', function()
{
    let change_id = $( 'textarea.name' ).val()
    console.log ( 'Approval for ' + change_id )
    socket.emit( 'change approval', change_id )
} )
```

Each row has a specific ID tied to it which I have put in the **name** field of the Bootstrap text area. So I have something unique about each row to reference, but I am just unsure on how to do that in JavaScript from a click action.

Comment: Just use the selector not by ID, by class or other. `$('.table-class .button-class').on('click', ...` for example

Comment: IMO, AJAX is enough for your use case.

Comment: @GreyLi Does Ajax update all users that are currently viewing the page?

Comment: No, it will only update one client...

Comment: @NikitaUmnov Thanks! That worked along with help from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kcka5WBMktw